# Removal failed, reverting .\composer.json to its original content

Tags: php, laravel

I want remove "irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk" package from my laravel project.
but whenever I tried, I saw this error:

> Removal failed, reverting .\composer.json to its original content.
>   I test with php v7 & 7.1&7.2&7.3
>   But not solved
>   I put this command:
>   Composer remove irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

I used from this command:
composer remove irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

Comment: Could you show us the entire command line output and the exact command you run to remove the package?

Comment: I added it in my question

Comment: It would help to post the command that you tried to execute.

Comment: `composer remove irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk`

Comment: just remove `irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk` from your `composer.json` file and run `composer update`.